# PHP MySQL select all matching rows and echo another table's rows

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have 2 table message and answer. where message id = answer id. I want select using message. when message = hi then expected answer hello, hey.

```
Message Table:
|  id  |  message |
|   1  |    hi    |
|   2  |    hi    |
|   3  |    Hi    |
```

and answer table:

```
| id | answer |
| 1  | hello  |
| 2  | hey    |
| 3  | Hello  |
```

I already tried:
$inp = "hi";

```
SELECT * FROM message JOIN answer ON message.message = answer.answer WHERE message='$inp'"
```

Comment: Please share your latest code attempt; this would help us in pointing you to right direction.

Comment: ```SELECT * FROM answer JOIN message ON message.id= answer.id WHERE message='$inp'" ``` Any luck with this.

Comment: Always join using the appropriate relationships. As specified in previous comment, you should using `id` not `message/answer`

Comment: Also, Your code is open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/2469308) related attacks. Please learn to use [Prepared Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code :

```
"SELECT * FROM message JOIN answer ON message.id= answer.id WHERE message.message='".$inp."'";
```

Answer (score 1):

use common b/w each table in your case id so query should be..

`SELECT * FROM message JOIN answer ON answer.id = message.id WHERE message = 'hi';`

rest in php you should use different ways to run query like prepared statements in order to avoid sql injection or concatenate the variables

like

`'SELECT * FROM message JOIN answer ON answer.id = message.id WHERE message = "'.$input.'"';`

or **mysqli_prepare()** **bind_params()**

or learn using **PDO** which is good to avoid sql injections as well as supports multiple db drivers which make your work more dynamic and flexible.